# UDF Regular Expressions for maria db

Tags: regex, user-defined-functions, mariadb

I've found this really good user defined functions for [using regular expressions in mysql](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php)
However when trying to instal I get can't find mysql library

```
checking for mysqlbin... dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
checking for mysql_config... no
no
configure: error: "Can't find mysql library"
```

The site says `If mysql is an unusual place, you might need to add --with-mysql=<mysql directory>/bin/mysql_config`

I can't find mysql_config

```
/var/log/mysql
/var/lib/mysql
/var/lib/mysql/mysql
/usr/share/mysql
/usr/lib/mysql
/etc/mysql/
```

I am using ubuntu lucid lynx, any sugestions would be greatly appreciated
**EDIT** the installation worked thanks to `apt-get install libmariadbclient16-dev` however now `preg_replace('/i/','a','ia')` returns `6161` instead of `ii`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install libmysqlclient-dev ( or libmariadbclient16-dev if you wish ) to get mysql_config.

Answer (score 0):

For centos:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-devel
```

Before you need to choose mariadb repo at: https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=timeweb&distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos6-amd64--centos6&version=10.0

ps: "3. Choose a Version" means maria db version!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg/issues/5

```
mysql_config not found was a good clue : Had to install - 
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```